# Проблема с html и css

Tags: html, css

После перемещения папки с сайтом в другое место, на сайте пропадают отступы, некоторые картинки. На моем пк сайт выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При переносе сайта на флешку/другой пк он выглядит как на втором изображении.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чём проблема?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 1.23;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1900px;

    margin: 0 auto;
}



/* Page
====================*/

.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

    background: #fff url("../img/maxresdefault.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}



/* Header
====================*/

.header {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.header-inner {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-brand {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.header-nav {
    display: flex;
}

.header-nav-link {
    margin-left: 50px;

    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;

    transition: color .2s linear;
}

.header-nav-link:hover {
    color: #15ff00;
}



/* Cover
====================*/

.cover {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 184px;

    margin: 0 auto;
}

.title {
    font-size: 90px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
}



/* Arrow
====================*/

.img-cont {
    width: 40px;
    height: 29px;
    margin: 466px auto 0 auto;
}



/* Content
====================*/

.sub-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #178745;
    font-weight: 500;

    margin: 74px auto 0 auto;
}

.paragraph {
    font-size: 37px;

    margin: 80px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.paragraph-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.paragraph-link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
    <title>Экологические связи человека</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="page">
        <!--Header-->
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-inner">
                    <div class="header-brand">
                        Экология
                    </div>

                    <nav class="header-nav">
                        <a class="header-nav-link" href="index.html">Главная</a>
                        <a class="header-nav-link" href="#sub-title">Содержание</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.container -->
        </header>


        <div class="cover">
            <h1 class="title">Экологические связи человека</h1>
        </div>


        <div class="img-cont">
            <img class="arrow" src="img/arrow.svg" alt="arrow">
        </div>

    </div><!-- /.page -->

    <!--Content-->
    <h2 class="sub-title" id="sub-title">Содержание</h2>
    <ol>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">Человек как биосоциальный вид</a></li>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">Особенности пищевых и информационных связей человека</a></li>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">Использование орудий и энергии</a></li>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">История развития экологических связей человечества. Древние гоминиды</a></li>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">История развития экологических связей человечества. Человек разумный</a></li>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">История развития экологических связей человечества. Современность</a></li>
        <li class="paragraph"><a class="paragraph-link" href="">История развития экологических связей человечества. Будущее</a></li>
    </ol>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что на вашем пк для страницы с вашей локальной версией в браузере уменьшен масштаб. Это можно заметить даже на скриншотах, на первом скрине текст меньше. И у вас нет никаких отступов по краям, а стоит ограничение в 1900px, что при нормальных масштабах с учетом скролла практически равно 0

Comment: Спасибо, моя внимательность подкачала)

Comment: @Nitrolacs пожалуйста. Можете отметить решением..

Answer (score 0):

1. Пути к картинкам не относительные.
2. Пути к стилевым файлам не относительные.

Скорее всего прописано так: "/styles/style1.css"
А надо так: "styles/style1.css"

Comment: у меня прописано вот так href="css/style.css"

Comment: и все равно не работают некоторые свойства, такие как max-width и margin

Comment: ну значит дополняйте вопрос, пока что ничего не ясно - как все оформлено, куда и откуда переместили, зачем переместили, когда переместили и т.д.)))

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, надеюсь понятно выразил проблему